# Failed to build "cutorch" when install cutorch in luarocks

Tags: torch, luarocks

---

- Operating system version: Ubuntu18.04
- CUDA toolkit version:CUDA toolkit 10.1 update 2
- CUDnn version: 7.6.2.24

---

luarocks install cutorch

The following is my error content:

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "THC" in directory /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-8576/cutorch/lib/THC

- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!-
  See also "/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-8576/cutorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-8576/cutorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Error: Build error: Failed building.

P.S.
I have solved the problem of not being able to generate "Error generating file" through TORCH_NVCC_FLAGS="-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__" ./install.sh and ./update

Answer (score 0):

```
export TORCH_NVCC_FLAGS="-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__" && luarocks install cutorch
```